# merging two dataframes and reducing the number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_dates, df_ratios. Both dataframes have the same dimensions 150 x 4. The both have a column which is a security id and this column is the same in both dataframes.

```
df_dates
id     col1       col2       col3        col4
1sds   nan        nan        20200108    nan
bhu6   20190404   nan        nan         nan
lm55   nan        nan        20200623    20201215
bn34   nan        nan        nan         nan


df_ratios
id     col1       col2       col3        col4
1sds   nan        nan        1.34        nan
bhu6   2.6        nan        nan         nan
lm55   nan        nan        0.23        0.45
bn34   nan        nan        nan         nan
```

What I need is shown below. Basically where there is a date in df_dates there will be a corresponding number in df_ratios & I want to align them together & any nan's to be ignored. The only way I know how to solve this problem is to simply loop through each row and column in the dataframes and apply some simple logic. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in pandas?

```
df_result
id     dates      ratios
1sds   20200108   1.34
bhu6   20190404   2.6
lm55   20200623   0.23        
lm55   20201215   0.45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DataFrames` are definitely aligned, you can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
(pd.concat([df_dates.set_index('id').stack().rename('dates'),
            df_ratios.set_index('id').stack().rename('ratios')], axis=1)
 .reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True))
```

[out]

```
     id       dates  ratios
0  1sds  20200108.0    1.34
1  bhu6  20190404.0    2.60
2  lm55  20200623.0    0.23
3  lm55  20201215.0    0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

we can melt & concat if your results are ordered correctly.

```
new_df = pd.concat([
    pd.melt(df1, id_vars="id",value_name='month').drop("variable", axis=1),
    pd.melt(df2, id_vars="id",value_name='ratio').drop(["variable","id"], axis=1)
],
axis=1
).dropna()
```

---

```
print(new_df)

      id       month    ratio  
1   bhu6  20190404.0   2.60
8   1sds  20200108.0   1.34
10  lm55  20200623.0   0.23
14  lm55  20201215.0   0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate `Series` objects from each data frame, then merge then on the index.

```py
s1 = df_dates.set_index('id').stack().astype(int)
s2 = df_ratios.set_index('id').stack()

s1.name = 'dates'
s2.name = 'ratios'

pd.merge(s1, s2, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index(level=0)
# returns:
        id     dates  ratios
col3  1sds  20200108    1.34
col1  bhu6  20190404    2.60
col3  lm55  20200623    0.23
col4  lm55  20201215    0.45
```